# Can I tell an XmlTextWriter to write <element/> instead of <element />?

Tags: .net, python, xml

I have a situation where XML data is being processed by two different mechanisms. In one place it is being processed using Python's xml.dom.minidom library. In the other, similar processing is being performed in .NET, via an XmlTextWriter.

In the output generated by the Python code, empty elements are written <ElementName/> (with no space before the element close). In the .NET code, a space is being inserted (resulting in <ElementName />). This makes no difference whatsoever to the validity or meaning of the XML, but it does cause the output to be detected as different when the two outputs are compared.

Is there any way to tell the XmlTextWriter not to include the extra space? Failing that, is there any way to include the extra space in the Python-generated output (short of messing with the library source, which wile possible is something I consider undesirable ;-))?

**Update:** Perhaps I should explain what I'm trying to do instead of just describing the problem. It's possible that I'm making things more complicated / painful than I should.

What I really need is some mechanism to determine that the structure represented by the XML has not been modified. I was originally flattening the XML (which eliminated whitespace issues when everything was being done in .NET world), then calculating an appropriately salted hash of the data. Is there a better mechanism I could / should be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not the answer you are after: Don't compare the XML output as pure text. We do that for our unit tests (two apps which communicate via xml messages) and it's brittle, easy to break, annoying and requires a lot of maintenance. You should parse the xml output and compare the structure - it will take more work to write a tool like that (maybe there is alrady one around) but when the output slightly changes again in the next version of any of the libraries it will still work.

**Edit**: Ok, now that you explained your problem a bit more, let me see if I understand it correctly: You have some data for which you create XML output. Sometimes via .NET and sometimes via Python. Let's say you create the output via .NET then you calculate a hash on it and store that. Later you produce the output via Python which should have the same content and you also calculate a hash for it. Now the two hashes are not equal because of the white space issue.

If that's the case you could walk the XML document and calculate the hash based on the seen nodes with their attributes and values. A simpler approach would be to strip all irrelevant white spaces from the output (no matter where the output comes from) and then do your hash calculation. You [can do that in Python](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/551778-unprettify-xml-strip-irrelevant-spaces-and-newline/) ;)

Comment: Some software (as WinMerge) lets you configure which elements can be compared and which not. At work we always disable "white space" when comparing source files.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As you may have seen, I updated the question a little to describe what I am trying to accomplish (as opposed to the problem in the mechanism I am currently trying to use) in the hope that I've overlooked something. I suspect I'm going to have to do something a little fancier than I was originally planning.

Comment: While it's not the answer I was hoping for, the suggestion described in the update (walking the XML) comes closest to what I eventually implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that the problem only occurs if you set the `Indent` property in the `XmlWriterSettings` to `true`. When `Indent == false`, there is no space inserted. But if you want indentation, you have to live with that space.

So perhaps the solution to your program is to turn off indentation in both tools?

This is unfortunate, because it's *almost* possible to change that behavior.

The implementation of `XmlWriter` actually calls `XmlWriterSettings.CreateWriter` to create a writer based on the settings you pass. If `Indent == true`, then it creates an `XmlEncodedRawTextWriterIndent`, which is an internal class derived from the abstract `XmlWriter`. It overrides `WriteFullEndElement` and inserts that space.

In theory, you could create your own class derived from `XmlEncodedRawTextWriterIndent` that overrides `WriteFullEndElement`. If you could do that, it'd be easy to prevent the indentation. But you can't do that because it's an `internal` class (internal to `System.Xml`). Even if you could subclass `XmlEncodedRawTextWriterIndent`, you'd have the problem that `XmlWriterSettings.CreateXmlWriter` doesn't have a way to instantiate your class, and `XmlWriterSettings` is `sealed`.

I imagine there are good reasons for effectively preventing creation of custom `XmlWriter` classes, although they escape me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would just post-process the output to do search/replace instead of trying to mess with the library

Comment: This probably isn't a good idea. A `CDATA` section could contain the character sequence ` /> ` , which would break the simple post-processing step (i.e. replacing all ` /> ` with `/>`. Attempts to code around that will likely meet with limited success and be more trouble than they're worth.

Comment: @JimMischel, I was thinking of search/replace with the full "<element/>" string

Comment: That's certainly possible, although as Jim points out CDATA sections might cause problems.

Comment: But the CDATA could contain the full "<element />" string, as well. In addition, if there are lots of different elements then you'd have do a separate replace for each one and if you modified the format you'd have to include that new element in your list of replacements. Whereas this solution could work, it would be brittle and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for file integrity wouldn't a MD5 (or something similar) of the file be sufficient?

Comment: The challenge is that the file needs to be self-validating. That is to say the validation code cannot be distributed separately from the file. This means we can't calculate the hash of the file itself, because that would change when we embed the result of the hashing operation in the file. (And yes, I understand that I could strip out the hash result before verifying the file contents, I was just looking for an easier option. What I had come up with worked fine... all the time the content was being manipulated exclusively by the .NET framework XML libraries.)

Answer (score 0):

compare xml files with [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net) Library. This library comes in both java and .net

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I don't actually have an XML file to compare with. My goal is to have a single XML file, and a mechanism (encapsulated within that same XML file) to ensure that the underlying structure has not changed. It doesn't matter if the whitespace has changed. In fact it doesn't even matter if the order of the elements and/or attributes have changed as long as a given element still has the same set of attributes, and each leaf node still has the same content.